Can't use personal email with Graph API after setting Tenant ID to "common"
I'm attempting to use Microsoft's Graph API to access calendar information on an application I'm building, using C# and .NET. As I understand it, you must set the TenantId while setting up authentication to "common", as this will allow either Microsoft emails or personal emails to use the app registration.
It was working as expected on my personal email I was using for development, but then it stopped allowing personal emails:

I'm not certain if this is because of changes I made to my code or something on the back-end changed, but I can't seem to fix this issue.
Here's the pertinent code:
 private const string TENANT_ID = "common";
 private const string CLIENT_ID = "<CLIENT_ID>";

 private static readonly string[] s_scopes = new[] { "Calendars.Read" };

 private static readonly FileInfo s_authPath = new FileInfo("./csOutlookStorage");
 private static readonly string s_tokenCacheName = "OwsAuthToken";

 private GraphServiceClient _client;

 public bool AccountLinked => s_authPath.Exists;

 public async Task InitializeAsync(CancellationToken token = default)
 {
     var credentialOptions = new InteractiveBrowserCredentialOptions()
     {
         TenantId = TENANT_ID,
         ClientId = CLIENT_ID,
         TokenCachePersistenceOptions = new TokenCachePersistenceOptions() { Name = s_tokenCacheName },
         RedirectUri = new Uri("http://localhost:3006")
     };
     InteractiveBrowserCredential credential;

     if(!AccountLinked)
     {
         credential = new InteractiveBrowserCredential(credentialOptions);
         var authRecord = await credential.AuthenticateAsync(token);

         using (var authRecordStream = s_authPath.Open(FileMode.Create))
         {
             await authRecord.SerializeAsync(authRecordStream);
         }
     }

...
    _client = new GraphServiceClient(credential, s_scopes);

I'd appreciate any help in this matter. Thanks very much

Initially, register one multi-tenant Entra ID application with "Supported account type" as below:

To access calendar information, make sure to assign Calendars.Read permission of "Delegated" type in application as below:

While using interactive flow, you need to add http://localhost/ as redirect URI in "Mobile & Desktop application" platforms and enable public clients as below:

To access calendar information via Graph API by signing in with personal accounts, you can make use of below sample code:
using Azure.Identity;
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        GetCalendar().Wait();
    }

    static async Task GetCalendar()
    {
        var scopes = new[] { "Calendars.Read" };

        // Multi-tenant apps can use "common",
        var tenantId = "common";

        // Value from app registration
        var clientId = "appId";

        var options = new InteractiveBrowserCredentialOptions
        {
            TenantId = tenantId,
            ClientId = clientId,
            AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud,
            RedirectUri = new Uri("http://localhost"),
        };

        var interactiveCredential = new InteractiveBrowserCredential(options);

        var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(interactiveCredential, scopes);
        var result = await graphClient.Me.Calendar.GetAsync();

        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result, Formatting.Indented);
        Console.WriteLine("Get calendar API response:");
        Console.WriteLine(json);
    }
}

When you run the code, it will open browser and asks you to pick an account like this:

You can also pick personal account here to sign in, that gives you consent prompt in next step as below:

After approving the consent, if authentication is successful you will get below screen:

When you return to the application now, you can find calendar API response in output console like this:

References:
Choose a Microsoft Graph authentication provider - Microsoft Graph
Get calendar - Microsoft Graph v1.0

Hi Sridevi, thanks for the response. Just to confirm,

"Supported application type" is set to "Accounts in any organizational directory... and personal Microsoft accounts"
I have two permissions for the app, "User.Read" and "Calendars.Read". Both are delegated permissions.
I have used "http://localhost" as a RedirectUrl and checked the "Allow public client flows" button.
Tenant Id is set as "common" in my application, and RedirectUri is set to "http://localhost" in my InteractiveBrowserCredential object

And it's still only allowing organizational emails.

Could you confirm how you are passing scope in your code and what values you used in code? Please include those lines of code too by editing your question

I've added the way I'm using scopes. To summarize, I have a static string
private static readonly string[] s_scopes = new[] { "Calendars.Read" };
And I'm assigning it when I create the graph client:
_client = new GraphServiceClient(service._credential, s_scopes);
Thanks for your help

Could you try running the sample code that I provided in my answer once and confirm whether it's working in your environment or not?

It may be worth mentioning that since I've posted this question I've tried to use MSAL instead of Azure Identity and it worked just fine - I was able to use personal emails. I'd rather not have to use HTTP requests and parse JSON responses directly though, and I don't see an easy way to provide an IPublicClientApplication to a GraphServiceClient

Okay, yes, your code is working just fine. I'm not certain what I'm doing differently, but it looks like it has something to do with my implementation.
It looks like the app registration is set up properly though, which is really what I was concerned about. I really appreciate all your help!

This might be a separate question, but I believe the problem I'm running into is due to the fact that I'm actually trying to call _client.Me.Calendars.GetAsync(), which lists all calendars, rather that just the user's default calendar. Is there any additional permissions that are required to read a user's list of calendars?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
